# Sorting key vlaue pairs output from the reducer

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

My `job` contains a `mapper` and a `reducer`. The `reducer` emits `key` `value` pairs where the `key` is the name of the student and the `value` is the gpa. The `reducer` computes the gpa. How can I make it so the `reducer` outputs are sorted on the `value`(gpa)?
Reducer code:

```
public class ReducerClass extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
      public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
          Context context)
          throws IOException, InterruptedException {
          int i = 0;
          int total = 0;
          for (IntWritable value : values) {
              i++;
              total = total + value.get();
          }
          context.write(key, new IntWritable(total));
      }
}
```

Comment: Does the reducer emit a list of key value pairs or just one pair? If it's just one pair what do you mean by sorted?

Comment: @A.sharif: Yeah, it outputs a series of key value pairs.

Comment: what's the datatype you get back from the reducer? a Hashmap?

Comment: Just key value pairs: key (Text) and value (IntWritable)

Comment: Can you add the reducer code to your question?

Comment: That doesn't compute the GPA? Adding up the grades won't get you the GPA. You need to multiply each grade by it's credit hours. Then add all of them up and divide it by the total number credit hours. Back to the question you just want "values" to return as sorted?

Comment: @A.sharif: Lemme rephrase it: I just need the top 5 students based on their GPA.

Comment: That's not the part that's confusing me. The parts that are confusing are:
1. What var holds the GPA?
2. How is that var returned?

Comment: From what I understand from this It is only called once per student. There is no list to sort. What method calls the reducer?

Comment: You are right.The reducer gets called once per student. How can I process the the key value pairs output by the reducers, so I can print just the top 5?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing is using secondary sort.[here](http://www.bigdataspeak.com/2013/02/hadoop-how-to-do-secondary-sort-on_25.html). The idea is adding the value also inside the reducer key(a composite key), and allow hadoop do the sorting at the output of map. This requires more changes to your existing design.

Another way(may be more easier), is once your current job is done, you can give the output of first job to second job, and interchange the key and value. In this case, the second job can have only a map, and the output will be shown as sorted based on gpa. Any repeated students, with same gpa, can come as a list for a specific gpa.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to sort the output in the reducer's cleanup method.

Comment: add as a comment your answer